# Entity Framework returns empty object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a paginated lookup to which I decided to add a total count, so that the front-end webpage can get the total (non-paginated) count and the paginated list in one API call. To do this, I created a wrapper class to contain the previously working List and the total count:

```
public class ReturnList<T>
{
  public List<T> list;
  public int unpaginatedLength;

  public ReturnList(List<T> list, int unpaginatedLength)
  {
    this.list = list;
    this.unpaginatedLength = unpaginatedLength;
  }
}
```

Then in my get:

```
[HttpGet("get")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ReturnList<dynamic>>> Get(params)
{
  List<dynamic> myList = await GetListSomehow();  // Using dynamic because I'm specifying columns to return
  int totalLength = await GetLengthSomehow();
  ReturnList returnList = new ReturnList<dynamic>(myList, totalLength);
  return Ok(returnList);
}
```

When I inspect everything in the debugger, everything looks like I expect it (`returnList` has a `List` (or an array, when I tried swapping out the types) with all the right objects, and an `int` with the expected length) to look up until it returns, but when I receive the reply in the front-end, the body of the response is just an empty `{}`. Is there something I'm missing to get the values to return across the internet correctly?

Comment: Try making the fields in ReturnList<T> into properties.  The use of dynamic here is a concern too.  Why not use a concrete type for your return type?  You mention selecting columns requiring you to use the dynamic type, which does not make sense to me, can you please explain?

Comment: @hijinxbassist: If you want to return only a subset of the columns on your object, it's no longer going to be the same type.

Comment: @hijinxbassist: Yep, the properties were what I was missing. I feel silly now. If you want to type it up as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Awesome, glad the solution ended up being simple.  Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the fields inside of ReturnList to properties.

```
public class ReturnList<T>
{
    public List<T> list { get; set; }
    public int unpaginatedLength { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the json serializer only serializes properties, while ignoring fields.